# Jfrog REST API Jenkins Groovy status code: 404, reason phrase: Not Found

Tags: rest, jenkins-groovy

I have a Groovy script which is run in the Jenkins script console.  The script uses the JFrog Rest API to run some queries.  One of which returns: status code: 404, reason phrase: Not Found

CURL:

```
$ curl -X GET -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:APIKey" https://OU.jfrog.io/OU/api/storage/test-repository/docker-log-gen/1.12/manifest.json?properties
{
  "properties" : {  ...  },
  "uri" : "https://OU.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/storage/test-repository/docker-log-gen/1.12/manifest.json"
}
```

WGET

```
$ wget --header="X-JFrog-Art-Api:APIKey" https://OU.jfrog.io/OU/api/storage/test-repository/docker-log-gen/1.12/manifest.json?properties
--2020-01-14 13:12:16--  https://OU.jfrog.io/OU/api/storage/test-repository/docker-log-gen/1.12/manifest.json?properties
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

---

Jenkins Groovy

```
def restClient = new RESTClient('https://OU.jfrog.io')
restClient.headers['X-JFrog-Art-Api'] = 'APIKey'
println(restClient.get(path: '/OU/api/storage/test-repository/docker-log-gen/1.12/manifest.json?properties', requestContentType: 'text/plain') )

groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: status code: 404, reason phrase: Not Found
```

Other rest calls (api/docker) are made prior to this one in the script and return successfully.  I am unable to identify a cause for this response, as shown the command-line calls return the expected JSON.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The part after the first question mark is not the URI path component.

```
println(restClient.get(path: '/OU/api/storage/test-repository/docker-log-gen/1.12/manifest.json', query: ['properties': ''] , requestContentType: 'text/plain').data.text )

{
  "properties" : {  ...  },
  "uri" : "https://OU.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/storage/test-repository/docker-log-gen/1.12/manifest.json"
}
```